# Pre-populate data in order to edit in React js and material-table

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, material-table

I would like to perform an edit operation using a pop up modal in react js and material-table.
I got the the modal to work but I am stuck with pre-populating the form in the modal

in my code i have tried something but it seems it is not working, because fields are not pre-populated or customerId is null for some reason

[image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLiKP.png)

```
const handleEditClick = (rowData) => {
    setRecordForEdit(rowData);
    setEditDialogOpen(true);
  }
```

```
<MaterialTable
            title="Under Construction"
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            icons={tableIcons}
            //isLoading={loading}
            onRowClick={handleDoubleRowClick}
            actions={[
              {
                icon: "Edit",
                tooltip: "Edit",
                disabled: false,
                onClick: (event, rowData) => {
                  const rowJson = JSON.stringify(rowData, null, 2);
                  handleEditClick(rowData);
                },
              },
            ]}
            options={{
              filtering: false,
              exportButton: true,
              actionsColumnIndex: -1,
              pageSizeOptions: [10, 25, 50],
              pageSize: 10,
              paginationType: "normal",
              addRowPosition: "first",
              rowStyle: (rowData) =>
                rowData?.customerId === selectedRow?.customerId
                  ? { background: "#8BCDFF" }
                  : {},
              headerStyle: {
                textAlign: "center",
              },
            }}
            editable={{
              onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
                new Promise((resolve) => {
                  handleRowDelete(oldData, resolve);
                }),
            }}
          />
```

```
const CustomerForm = ({open, onClose, recordForEdit}) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    customerId: recordForEdit.customerId || 0,
    customerCode: recordForEdit.customerCode || "",
    customerDescription: recordForEdit.customerDescription || "",
    customerAddress: recordForEdit.customerAddress || "",
    customerContact: recordForEdit.customerContact || "",
    customerSite: recordForEdit.customerSite || "",
    customerDistanceOffice: recordForEdit.customerDistanceOffice || "",
    imageSrc: recordForEdit?.imageSrc || "",
    imageFile: recordForEdit?.imageFile || null,
  });


  const initialFieldValues = {
    customerId: 0,
    customerLogoName: "",
    customerCode: "",
    customerDescription: "",
    customerAddress: "",
    customerSite: "",
    customerContact: "",
    customerDistanceOffice: "",
    imageSrc: Img,
    imageFile: null,
  };

  const resetForm = () => {
    setFormData(initialFieldValues);
  };

  const clearForm = (e) => {
    resetForm();
  }


  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
     const form = document.querySelector('#customerForm');
     const formData = new FormData(form);
     formData.append('customerId', form.customerId.value)
     const data = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()));
     
     console.log(form)

     api
       .put(`Customer/${formData.customerId}`, data)
       .then((res) => {
         const dataUpdate = [...data];
         const index = data.tableData.id;
         dataUpdate[index] = formData;
         setFormData([...dataUpdate]);
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         toast.error("Problem Updating", {
           position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
         });
         console.log(err);
       });

     clearForm();

  };

  const showPreview = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
      let imageFile = e.target.files[0];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (x) => {
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          imageFile,
          imageSrc: render.result,
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
    } else {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        imageFile: null,
        imageSrc: Img,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose}>
      <DialogTitle>Edit Customer</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} id="customerForm">
          <img className="w-full" src={formData.imageSrc} alt="" />
          <input
            className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
            id="image-uploader"
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={showPreview}
            
          />
          <TextField
            className="w-[80%] md:w-1/2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            label="id"
            name="customerId"
            value={formData.customerId}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setFormData({ ...formData, customerId: event.target.value })
            }
            disabled
            variant="outlined"
          />
          <TextField
            className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            label="Code"
            name="customerCode"
            value={formData.customerCode}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setFormData({ ...formData, customerCode: event.target.value })
            }
            variant="outlined"
          />
          <TextField
            className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 mb-2"
            label="Description"
            name="customerDescription"
            value={formData.customerDescription}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setFormData({
                ...formData,
                customerDescription: event.target.value,
              })
            }
            variant="outlined"
            //multiline
            //rows={4}
          />
          <TextField
            className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 mb-2"
            label="Address"
            name="customerAddress"
            value={formData.customerAddress}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setFormData({ ...formData, customerAddress: event.target.value })
            }
            variant="outlined"
          />
          <TextField
            className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 mb-2"
            label="Contact Info"
            name="customerContact"
            value={formData.customerContact}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setFormData({ ...formData, customerContact: event.target.value })
            }
            variant="outlined"
          />
          <TextField
            className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 mb-2"
            label="Site"
            name="customerSite"
            value={formData.customerSite}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setFormData({ ...formData, customerSite: event.target.value })
            }
            variant="outlined"
          />
          <TextField
            className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 mb-2"
            label="Distance from Office"
            name="customerDistanceOffice"
            value={formData.customerDistanceOffice}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setFormData({
                ...formData,
                customerDistanceOffice: event.target.value,
              })
            }
            variant="outlined"
          />
        </form>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button variant="secondary" type="button" onClick={onClose}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleFormSubmit}>
          Save
        </Button>
        <Button variant="secondary" type="button" onClick={clearForm}>
          Clear
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please write more information about the code bodies. Please only provide the code you need us to look at for this question.

Comment: @Luke Basically this is all the code related to my situation. handleeditClick is a function that should pass rowData and open the modal. MaterialTable is my table containing my data with actions being the main trigger to open the modal. CustomerForm is the actual modal which i want to edit the data and update it

Comment: So after you open the modal, you'll need to run `api.get` and obtain the data from the database, set the states, and then populate the form. Is that correct?

Comment: @Luke seeing that the data is already in the table (material-table), a get request is not needed. The problems comes with clicking the edit button (which should open the modal) and upon opening the modal the fields are already populated in terms of the row where the edit button is clicked

Comment: Can you console the data here and see it as expected? `onClick: (event, rowData) => {
                  const rowJson = JSON.stringify(rowData, null, 2);
                  handleEditClick(rowData);
                },`

Comment: Yes I can, The variable rowJson returns the data as a json object. handleEditClick(rowData) returns the data as an array of objects

Comment: When you `setFormData` to populate the `state`, can you `console.log()` that?

Comment: I managed to get it working and by that, I mean pre-populating the fields, just having issues with the API by utilizing put.

Comment: Please write your solution in the answers box.